# How do I fix Chrome 'show in folder' to open in file explorer and not in new tab?

Tags: google-chrome, linux-mint, mate

When I click "show in folder" Chrome opened the folder in a new tab.
How can I fix this such that Chrome opens the folder with my standard file explorer (caja)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just execute the following lines and the problem will be fixed. No restart (neither of chrome, nor of anything else) is needed:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libfile-mimeinfo-perl
$ mimeopen -d /home/moose/Documents
Please choose a default application for files of type inode/directory

1) Caja  (caja-folder-handler)
2) Other...

use application #1
Opening "/home/moose/Documents" with Caja  (inode/directory)
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. `xdg-mime` did. I guess it depends which system you use.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem after uninstalling pcmanfm and changing it for Thunar.

No need to install anything. Chromium/Chrome manages this function through xdg-open, and you have to modify it.

Check which is the default file manager in xdg-open:

```
$ xdg-mime query default inode/directory
```

It should give an unwanted one or one that is no longer installed.

Then set the desired default file manager in xdg-open. For caja it should be:

```
$ xdg-mime default caja.desktop inode/directory
```

or something really similar.
It worked immediately for me. I learnt it from: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xdg-open

Comment: This solved my problem in Manjaro linux. I had to use `pcmanfm.desktop` in place of `caja.desktop`

Comment: This also solved a problem where I had unintentially made sublimetext 3 my file manager: `xdg-mime query default inode/directory` gave me `sublime_text.desktop`, and `xdg-mime default nautilus.desktop inode/directory` changed it back.

Comment: I think this answer should be marked as solution as it's more general and not distributive-specific.

Comment: does the new setting "stick" after reboot?

Answer (score 2):

For me, further to **@elmanu's** answer `xdg-mime default caja.desktop inode/directory`, it was running

```
update-desktop-database ~/.local/share/applications/
```

which finally updated the default application.

After this, running `xdg-mime query default inode/directory` now showed the new default application.